# Where is wireless driver on CD? 

Tags: 10.04, wireless, drivers

I made an installation CD (10.04),  the CD has a driver for my wireless network card (in the trial version), how do I find the driver so I can use it with my new installation ?

I tried `whereis broadcom` but it found nothing.

EDIT:
Yes, using the live CD, an icon came up to install non-proprietary drivers, when I click install ... it say's ... downloading, the disk spins a bit ... and it installs.
From my installation there doesn't seem to be anything available ... thanks. 
EDIT:
Yes  grahammechanical, that fixed it thanks.

Comment: So, it worked on the LiveCD? Then you installed and it doesn't work from the installation?

Comment: I am not an expert so I guess that in a standard Ubuntu install the Additional Driver utility looks in pre-determined repositories which are on-line. In your case it is not looking on the CD. Would setting Software Sources to include the CD fix this issue? It is just a guess. so, I do not offer it as an answer.

Comment: @grahammechanical Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert so I guess that in a standard Ubuntu install the Additional Driver utility looks in pre-determined repositories which are on-line. In your case it is not looking on the CD. Would setting Software Sources to include the CD fix this issue?

(Comment by grahammechanical, which worked. Mark this as an answer and edit away this comment to remove the question from unanswered section)